# Remove All characters between two Tags in PHP

Tags: php, regex, text, replace

i'm trying to detect a tag and remove whole tag with the characters inside from a file in PHP. this is a part of text file that i want to replace it or remove it:

```
//CODE START//
Some Content Between Tags
//CODE END//
```

i wrote this code:

```
$File = file_get_contents('file.text');
$File = preg_replace( "#//CODE START//(.+?)//CODE END//#is", '', $File );
file_put_contents('new.text', $File);
```

problem is, the code is not working! with this one i can delete first line:

```
$File = preg_replace( "#//CODE START//#i", '', $File );
```

but how i can remove all those 3 lines? starting from **//CODE START//** all the way to **//CODE END//**.

thank you

**UPDATE:** i found it:

```
$File = preg_replace( "/\/\/CODE START\/\/(.+?)\/\/CODE END\/\//ims", '', $File );
```

Comment: did you try using the `m` modifier to allow for multi-line matching? http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: s may do the job as well.

Comment: how i can do that? where is the problem in my code?

Comment: Why did you change the delimiters in your update? It was much more readable with `#`.

Comment: could please show me the code with #?

Comment: `$File = preg_replace( '#//CODE START//(.*?)//CODE END//#is', '', $File );` should work. If not working then provide your input data

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Spot the difference:</strike>

```
//INSTALL END//
       ^^--- two L's

[..snip..] "#//INSTALL START//(.+?)//INSTAL END//#is", '', $File );
                                          ^---single L
```

Oh great, and a ninja edit just totally nukes this out of the water...